# Need help converting Vb.Net to Delphi (API Stuff (?))

Tags: vb.net, delphi, winapi, process

```
    Dim ThisModule As IntPtr
    Dim Proc As Process() = Process.GetProcessesByName("Sol")

    For i = 0 To Proc(0).Modules.Count - 1
        If (Proc(0).Modules(i).ModuleName.ToString.Contains("UxTheme")) Then
            ThisModule = Proc(0).Modules(i).BaseAddress
        End If
    Next
```

I have made this code, and works perfectly, but now... i want to make it in Delphi, the problem is... i have not the enough knowledge for make it, and... in google, i haven't found the information i need.

Thanks in advance!.

Comment: If the above code would have used the native Windows API, conversion would have been trivial (to someone fluent in Delphi). Now, the above doesn't; instead, the code makes heavy use of .NET classes (I think), which are not present in Delphi.

Comment: @Andreas The code didn't use native Windows API so OP has a real problem. What's more do you shun the VCL when writing VCL code so that  it would be easy to convert at some point in the future?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a lower level API, the tool help API.  A basic outline of how to get what you need is as follows:

1. Call `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot()` passing `TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS`.
2. Next walk the processes with `Process32First()` and `Process32Next()` until you find the process you want.
3. Call `CloseHandle()` to close the snapshot.
4. Call `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot()` again, this time passing `TH32CS_SNAPMODULE` and the desired process ID found in step 2.
5. Walk the modules with `Module32First()` and `Module32Next()` until you find the module you want.
6. Call `CloseHandle()` to close the snapshot.

Comment: Perfect dude, i have made the snippet, but... i can't paste it here, (by the characters limit).

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could use the free modules form [MadCollection](http://www.madshi.net/) (madKernel, if I'm not mistaken) which have such libraries. The coding are very near those of the OP. (I've used it to send messages to the parent process of one of my programs ).

**EDIT:**
About licensing troubles, see this quote from [Madshi.net](http://help.madshi.net/License.htm) license agreement page:

> FREEWARE PRODUCT(S)
>
> The packages "madBasic", "madKernel", "madShell"
>   and "madSecurity" may be used freely
>   for both non-commercial and commercial
>   use, without buying a license,
>   provided that:
>
> (1) The author
>   Mathias Rauen is given proper credit
>   for his work.
>
> (2) The licensee does
>   not claim that the library was written
>   by him.
>
> (3) If the software is  modified, any software containing  modifications must prominently state in the 
>   modified product or documentation
>
> ```
>   (a) that it has been modified,
>
>   (b) the identity of the person or entity that made the modifications
> ```
>
> and
>
> ```
>   (c) the date the modifications were made.
> ```
>
> (4) The mentioned packages must not be transferred to any third party unless
>         such third party receives a copy of this agreement and agrees to be bound
>         by all of its terms and conditions.

Comment: +1 This is a good option, but I would point out that it is only free for non-commercial use.

Comment: At least in the installer I have here, the modules **madKernel, madSecurity, madShell and madBasic** are marked as freeware. The restricition applies only to madExcept and madCodeHook. I can post a screenshot if needed.

Comment: And I used only the units madKernel and madStrings to solve my problem (I'm browsing my source code right now). So your consideration doesn't apply.

Comment: The madshi.net website seemed to suggest otherwise, but perhaps I was misreading it.

Comment: The site is misleading saying that only madBasic was freeware, but I believe the License Agreement is remove all doubt.